# ¿Cómo agregar Program.cs y Startup.cs en VsCode?

Tags: entity-framework, vscode, identity, dotnetcore

Al agregar Identity en la capa de persistencia de mi proyecto, me manda un error al correr el comando *dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -dc HospiEnCasaMascotas.App.Persistencia.AppContext --files "Account.Register;Account.Login;Account.Logout;Account.RegisterConfirmation"*

**error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point**

Buscando sobre el error, encuentro que es debido al no tener las clases Program.cs y Startup.cs. Veo que en Visual Studio es tan fácil como darle la indicación, pero en mi proyecto en vscode no tengo claro como hacerlo.

Si pudiese tener alguna guía, me sería de mucha ayuda. De antemano, gracias.

Comment: Eso lo genera todo solo al crear el proyecto... vos a que proyecto le agregaste identity?

Comment: Gracias por responder @gbianchi Inatalé identity en la capa de persistencia, separado de la capa de presentación. Sin embargo no corre el comando especificado. ¿Es una posibilidad agregar Identity en la capa de presentación, ya que esta tiene el archivo Program.cs? El proyecto es una webApp

Comment: no soy experto en el tema ni se a que llamas capa de persistencia... pero identity deberia ir en tu api...

Comment: La capa de persistencia es donde están las conexion a la base de datos y el AppContext

Comment: De seguro en un proyecto tienes la capa de presentacion y en otro la de persistencia. Tienes que referenciar los dos proyectos (click derecho sobre el proyecto y elige addreference o create reference, no recuerdo como se llama)

Comment: @HernánGarcia Sie te refieres a ProjectReference, la capa de presentación (Frontend), ya está haciendo referencia a la capa de persistencia (Base de Datos). Me queda como último recurso, instalar todos los paquetes de Identity en la capa de presentación, aunque no tendría mucha lógica para mí.